# Microsoft Edge Extension, how to manipulate popup.html DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, microsoft-edge-extension

I'm new on Browser Extension dev. 
I'm trying to do some easy stuff, but I don't really know why doens't work. 
What is the problem? I can't manipulate DOM of my popup.html file. 
Here an example:

```
<html>
<head>
 <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body id="content">
 <p> Hello world </p>
 <button id="go" />
</body>
</html>
```

And here my very simple main.js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

 $('#go').click( function(){

    $( "#content" ).empty();
    alert("Done");
 });
});
```

After click, the content of my Body seems doesn't disappear, but if I put an alert, I can see that my code work (when the alert show). But after click() event (when I close the alert), the popup file it's restored and paragraph is still here.

So, what I'm doing wrong? Can I manipulate the DOM of my popup file? Or my JS code need fix? 
I've made some tests, and I notice that any event, any data and any action die after click() event. 
I've also try

```
location.href = "other_page.html";
```

the redirect work, but as I said after click I return in popup.html file.

Thanks, I'm here for more specification

Comment: Your code works well at my end. Could you please more details, such as `manifest.json` and Edge version?

Comment: That's my manifest: http://pastebin.com/rXGWMKZe

Comment: `"browser_style": true` is not supported in Microsoft Edge, are you sure the extension can be successfully loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem.... 
I think Edge doesn't like jquery click() function.

Try with this:

```
document.getElementById("logout").addEventListener("click", function() { 
$( "#content" ).empty();
alert("Done");
}
```

I've solved in this way :)